# How to change the default domain suffix for iPad Pro on screen keyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, safari

As title, how can I change the default domain suffix to `.com` for my iPad Pro on screen keyboard (Safari browser) as shown below? Because I use the suffix `.com` more than other domain suffix. Every time I type the URL, I required to hold the `.co.uk` key in order to get `.com` which is quite inconvenient. I try google search but I didn't get any related result. Any solution? Sorry for my bad English.

Here are some additional information of my device

1. iPad Pro 12.9 inches
2. Version 10.0.2
3. iPad Language : English (U.K.)
4. Region : Malaysia
5. Keyboard : English (UK) QWERTY
6. Application : Safari Browser

[image: ios keyborad]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined by the keyboard locale you select. It can't be changed independently of this. The .com TLD is used on the US keyboard. To change to a US keyboard, go to Settings → Keyboards → Keyboards → Add New Keyboard → English, then use the globe button to switch keyboards.